# Loading multiple extjs comboboxes in a form

Tags: extjs

another ComboBox question.

In my table there are about 10 fields that are foreign keys, all presented with comboboxes.
How to fill all this combos in a form, without go 10 times to server to load the store of each one?

Answer (score 2):

Are they stored as separate tables on the back end? If yes, then the correct way would be *to load them going to the server 10 separate times*. You can optimize this scenario by:

- loading them all simultaneously
- loading them all before you get to that page in advance

But you still would want to have 10 different stores in your ExtJs application.

If you wish to combine them into single store remember couple things

- you would need to add additional field into this combined table so you can distinguish different lists.
- you would load them all at once
- then you would still need to separate them into different store objects because otherwise different UI components (comboboxes) won't be able to show different sets of data

Comment: Supose that change the combobox to a custom editField that holds the "id" and "display" values. I will be able to use a single store, but even so, I need a call to get regular fields a another call to get foreign keys pair(id and display value).

Comment: Yes. What's the problem with loading several stores?

Comment: The problem is the time it takes.

Comment: Load them all at the same time, when your start application

Comment: I can´t do this, because some table has thousands of records.

Comment: The idea is load only the record that will be displayed in the form. To search for another result, I think to open a filter window.

Comment: Then you need to use server-side filtering and bring originally only those key-value pairs from 10 store that match your record. And if user decide to open up combobox - you can dynamically load full store then.

Answer (score 1):

Well known problem :) Typically when I have structure like this

```
var data = {
    ForeignKeyObjectId: 123,
    ForeignKeyObject: {
        Id: 123,
        SomeValue: 'Some text 1'
    },

    SomeOtherObjectId: 456,
    SomeOtherObject: {
        Id: 456,
        SomeValue: 'Some text 2'
    }
    //, ... same 8 times more
}
```

I have to load each combo manually:

```
var combo1 = this.down('#foreignKeyObjectCombo');
combo1.setValue(data.ForeignKeyObject.Id);
combo1.setRawValue(data.ForeignKeyObject.SomeValue);
combo1.store.loadData([data.ForeignKeyObject], true);

var combo2 = this.down('#someOtherObjectCombo');
combo2.setValue(data.SomeOtherObject.Id);
combo2.setRawValue(data.SomeOtherObject.SomeValue);
combo2.store.loadData([data.SomeOtherObject], true);

// same 8 times more
```

In one of my previous projects on ExtJs 3 I made some overrides for form and combobox behaviour so that I could use `form.getForm().loadData(data)` once instead of manually setting value, rawValue like in this example. But that way was implicit, so I like more this way :)

Answer (score 0):

Example:

**Model 1**

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'EmployeeType',
        data : [
            {type: 1,    description: 'Administrative'},
            {type: 2,    description: 'Operative'},
        ]
    });
```

**Model 2**

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'BloodType',
    data : [
        {type: 1,    description: 'A+'},
        {type: 2,    description: 'B+'},
    ]
});
```

Even if your stores have Proxy, you can disable AutoLoad so you can load as many as you want in one single request like this:

Create the stores manually:

```
employeeType = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {model: EmployeeType});
bloodType = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {model: BloddType});
```

Create an Ajax request where you bring all combos at once:

```
Ext.ajax.request({
    url: './catalogs/getalldata',
    success: function(response) {
        var json = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
        employeeType.loadData(json.employeeTypes);
        bloodType.loadData(json.bloodTypes);
        //...
    } 
});
```